# Opencart Error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"During Payment Method Checkout

Tags: javascript, error-handling, opencart, payment-gateway

One of my Opencart stores seems keeps showing up an error during the last step before a customer is about to do a purchase.

I'm getting a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error message during the Payment Method checkout.

Here's the link to the test site: http://www.shaunmeilak.com/shibcadesign21-2/

It would be a massive favour to find out exactly whats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when your cart is producing a php error and returns it to your browser instead of the JSON object that the AJAX request is expecting. Check your error log in opencart/with your hosting and correct what is causing the error. It's most likely to be something trivial